# Join up two rows to one in Oracle Sql at a particular column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores transactions if this fomat

```
Tran_date  tran_id account_number tran_type amount
21-07-2017 M23     1234567890         D      50000
21-07-2017 M23     0987654321         C      50000
21-07-2017 M24     7654328900         D      20000
21-07-2017 M24     8845874588         C      20000
```

these are  debit and credit for two transactions. I am required to report this in one row for every transaction like this:

```
Tran_date  tran_id  src_acct    dest_acct   Amount
21-07-2017  M23     1234567890  0987654321  50000
21-07-2017  M24     7654328900  8845874588  20000
```

I have tried to select max of account Number grouping by account number but I am still getting individual rows. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT Tran_date, tran_id, MAX(Amount) AS Amount
       MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type = 'D' THEN account_number END) AS src_acct,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type = 'C' THEN account_number END) AS dest_acct
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Tran_date, tran_id
```

The query assumes the amount is the same between `'D'` and `'C'` records.

Answer (score 0):

Join will do also. Assuming `(tran_id, tran_type)` is unique

```
SELECT td.Tran_date, td.tran_id, td.account_number as src_acct, tc.account_number as dest_acct, td.Amount
FROM mytable td
JOIN mytable tc ON td.tran_type = 'D' AND tc.tran_type = 'C'AND tc.tran_id = td.tran_id;
```